# Rails: Writing data returned from outer join to csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'd like to do an outer join on two tables and then selecting certain columns and writing all rows to a CSV. It seems that the attributes belonging to the Article table are being added to `row_container` as expected but the one for the Author table (`author.name`) is throwing a NoMethodError, I assume because ruby is looking for a method called `author.name`. Can anyone provide any tips on this?

```
require 'csv'
data = Article.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN authors ON author_id = authors.id')
columns = ["title", "date", "author.name"]
CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << columns
  data.each do |row|
    row_container = []
    columns.each {|i| row_container << row.send(i) }
    csv << row_container
  end
end
```